# Use git auto stash option with untracked files

Tags: git

Setting the [`rebase.autoStash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt-rebaseautoStash) configuration variable to `true`, or specifying the [`--autostash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autostash) option for the `git rebase` command works as documented, but the untracked files are not included in the automatically generated stash.

I looked through the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), but couldn't find anything related to this issue.

Is there really no option to fix this?

Comment: seen that by default git is not tracking untracked files, to stash them it should then track the untracked files. It follows logically you have to track them first.

Comment: Not quite, as `stash` can [include untracked files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt---include-untracked) already.

Answer (score 1):

There is no integrated command.

You can add a wrapper script or an alias :

```
git config --global alias.strebase '! f (){ git stash -u; git rebase "$@"; }; f'
```

---

When you don't use autostash, staged files and modifications on tracked files will not block actions such as `git merge` or `git rebase`, but may participate in conflicts, and lead you to states where you can neither fix the issue at hand nor "come back to how it was".

When untracked files clash with tracked files from another commit, on the other hand, git blocks the action and let's you take the time to handle it as you intend.

`autostash` fixes the first situation ; the second situation may be annoying at times, but is less of a mess, and I'm not sure running `git stash -u` automatically would work for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but it wouldn't work for my case.